# Who needs a life? or who need a life?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am debating this with a friend, but we couldn't come to an agreement,
so I came here for you to help me on deciding which sentence is correct.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Have you done some research on it? What have you found?

Answer (score 3):

"Who needs a life" is the correct usage in this case.

"Who" in a question is always considered a singular subject, unless the object is explicitly plural, as in "who are they".

Think of "*who needs a life*" as a short version of "*who is that person* [singular] *that needs a life*", and it should make more sense.

Comment: Upvote for good advice, but in fact in "who are they" the subject is probably "they." Compare the similar "who am I," where we see the verb agrees in person with the following pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the word "who" as a noun corresponding to a group of people, or when you are just using it to ask a question about a group of people. "Who" is plural, specifically when you're asking questions such as "who are they" or "who are they going to help," or if you are going to use "who" to specify a group of people--> "Those who have no water should be given some." If you'd like to talk directly to a group of people though, "who" is always a singular noun. "Who will be coming to the party," or, "who here wants a drink."

Answer (score 1):

Singular Subject --> verb stem plus 'S'

Plural Subject --> verb stem without 'S'

Singular subjects: He, she, it, who, Joe, the doctor

Plural subjects: We, they, the doctors

The exceptions: I & you use the plural verb form

Who needs a life?

He needs a life. She needs a life.  The doctor needs a life.

Also, I need a life.  You need a life.  We need a life.  They need a life. And the doctors need a life.

Comment: This is blatant oversimplification.  "*The doctors **who need** a life should be considered too*".

Comment: It's not an oversimplification at all.  In fact, it's a confirmation of the rule.    The subject of "The doctors who need help." and "The doctors need help." is "The doctors".  A plural subject.  So the verb is plural.  Similarly, "The doctor needs help." and "The doctor who needs help." still uses the singular verb because the subject is singular, a doctor.

Comment: The subject is "who" and the simplification is when you say that it's a "singular subject".  It isn't.  Full sentence: "the doctors who need our help publish books".  Two subjects, two predicates.